# sticky nav, idk what's going on :\

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with my sticky nav. The problem seems to be that my JS is not applying the class I have told it to. you can view it live here http://test.makx.ca

Here is my code.

```
<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
nav = $('.nav-bar').offset();
if (nav.top <= scroll) {
  $('.nav-bar').toggleClass('sticky-nav');
} else {}
});
</script>
```

the HTML

```
<div class="row nav-row">
    <div id="nav-bar" class="medium-12 column nav-bar">
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing.php">pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="links-right">
            <li class="has-form">
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-7 small-7 columns">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="enter text">
                </div>
                <div class="large-3 small-4 pull-2 columns">
                    <a href="#" class="search button expand" style="padding-top: 0.6rem;
                    padding-bottom: 0.6rem;">Search</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.sticky-nav {
position: fixed;
top:0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

any feedback would be most welcoming. This has me and a friend completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector. `.nav-bar` is a class selector, but you want to select the element with the id `nav-bar`, not the class `nav-bar`. Use `#nav-bar` as the selector instead.

Unrelated to your question, but FYI: Your use of `toggleClass` is going to have some odd results; it will constantly be toggling the class on and off while the user scrolls.

Comment: Would you recommend the use of `addClass`? I also changed my selector to `#nav-bar` It still doesn't seem to be working :\ not even adding the class. Uploaded my changes to http://test.makx.ca

Comment: Well, that depends on what you're trying to do, which is not 100% clear to me. I'm not sure why any of this code is triggered by a scroll event in the first place. Why not just give your nav bar `position: fixed;` in the CSS and skip the jQuery entirely for this?

Comment: Well what i'm trying to do is make the nav stick to the top of the window once you scroll past the logo that is above the nav. I tried to do a `position:fixed;` but it's not giving me the outcome that I desire. Something similar to this http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

Comment: Okay, then, yes, you need addClass.

Comment: So I managed to figure out what was conflicting with the code and why it wasn't working. I had `overflow-x:hidden;` on my body and it was causing some issues. You're help was definitely appreciated Ed!

Comment: Glad to help! Because this helped you with the initial problem, please remember to accept it as the answer!